# You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded the latest Android SDK tools version 24.4.1. I used the command line to install SDKs. I typed `y` when asked

> Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-c81a61d9' [y/n]: y
>   after that install succeeded.

But when using Gradle 3.1 to build, the follows shows up

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>     [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
>     Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>     Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

I checked `~/.android` and `/opt/android-sdk` where Android tools are put. Neither contain folder named `licenses`.

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file

Comment: If on Windows, make sure to Run As Administrator

Comment: I have solved the problem by going to the Android Studio-> Tools -> SDK manager and on SDK Tools I have installed Google Play Licensing Library Android SDK Tools Android SDK Platform Tools and the problem have been solved.

Comment: it's showing me this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)

Answer (score 1014):

The way to accept license agreements from the command line has changed. You can use the SDK manager which is located at: `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin`

e.g on linux:

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/
```

Run the sdkmanager as follows:

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

e.g on Windows in administrative command prompt if needed:

```
cd /d "%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%/tools/bin"
```

Run the sdkmanager as follows:

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

And accept the licenses you did not accept yet (but need to).

For more details see the [Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html), although the current documentation is missing any description on the `--licenses` option.

### Warning

You might have two Android SDKs on your machine. Make sure to check both `~/Library/Android/sdk` and `/usr/local/share/android-sdk`! If unsure, fully [uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac) Android Studio from your machine and start with a clean slate.

> Update: **ANDROID_HOME** is deprecated, **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** is now the correct variable

Comment: I accepted all licenses and got message: `Accept? (y/N): y
All SDK package licenses accepted
done`  but error still appear.

Comment: We found out we had two Android SDK's installed. One which was in use by Gradle and one managed by Android Studio. It might be you have the same issue.

Comment: Hugo, where was that gradle one installed?

Comment: This allowed me to accept packages, but it didn't solve the initial problem for some reason. By the way, in my case the command that listed the licenses was `sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...

AND STILL DOES NOT WORK

Comment: @ShahidKarimi what ended up being the issue?

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, worked for me.

Comment: Hello, @BenjaminGruenbaum I am here once again after a year.

Comment: For  windows you have to go to C:\Users\shashank\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin, and run sdkmanager --licenses. and accept the licence which is not accepted.

Comment: for me, the following solution worked:
i went to this path - C:\Users\<your user profile>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
and ran these 2 commands in git bash: sdkmanager.bat --upgrade
and
sdkmanager.bat --licenses

Comment: @saike I had to same error as you. What I figured out was I had two ANDROID_HOME set. Delete the duplicate and try again!

Comment: `yes | sdkmanager --licenses > /dev/null`

Comment: @ShahidKarimi Run As Administrator on Windows

Comment: `yes | sudo sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: this dont work, when i run this it errors out as Error: Unknown argument --licenses

Comment: i found this one out https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#download-with-gradle

Comment: In Java 11 this will crash with NoClassDefFoundError. To work around this I had to modify `sdkmanager` by adding the following jars at the end of the `CLASSPATH` variable:
`:$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb-core.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb-impl.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb-api.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/activation.jar`. All these jars can be downloaded from Oracle website.

Comment: I have no idea, or care what the licences were. but it seems to be working now with my ionic project.

Comment: This worked for me, although, on MacOSX the licenses are put in a folder outside this path. You'll need to move the licenses into the sdk directory.

Comment: In my case, the android sdk folder had two instances of sdkmanager:

one in $ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager
and another on
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager

Had to run ./sdkmanager --licenses on both and the problem went away

Comment: This worked for android on MacOS as well.

Comment: It still didnt work until I reboot my windows PC.

Comment: My problem was also that I had 2 versions of sdk, on Windows.  After accepting the license in C:\Users\<your user profile>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin, it still wasn't working.  That's when I noticed my $ANDROID_HOME environment variable was pointing to the C:\Program Files\Android directory.  I updated to the C:\Users\..., restarted my command prompt session, and everything worked.

Comment: I've searched SO for over an hour to figure this out with no luck. On Windows 10 and absolutely none of the command line stuff has worked for me. Finally found a forum online that told me to:

go to Tools -> SDK manager and just download another SDK and it'll prompt me to accept the license.

Comment: Am I the only one getting error: `Unknown argument --licenses`?
I'm using Android SDK Tools 25.2.5

Comment: @Hugo love you man, it solved my issue but I need to downgrade my jdk to 8

Comment: Google has invalidated this answer. `sdkmanager --licenses` is no longer a thing.

Comment: "sdkmanager --licenses" hasn't worked in a long time, need to use "sdkmanager --update" now which sucks when you're trying to use a very specific version.

Comment: @saike You have to accept licence multiple times. You should press 'Y' multiple times

Comment: This worked on a Mac

Comment: no sdkmanager on WSL Debian

Comment: in my case path is C:\Users\os\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager --licenses

Comment: This no longer works in 2022 because the `tools` dir has been depreciated. Following the first answer here worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210100/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-annotation-xmlschema-when-accep

Answer (score 162):

You can install and accept the license of the SDK & tools via 2 ways:

### 1. Open the Android SDK Manager GUI via command line

Open the Android SDK manager via the command line using:

```
# Android SDK Tools 25.2.3 and lower - Open the Android SDK GUI via the command line
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools && ./android

# 'Android SDK Tools' 25.2.3 and higher - `sdkmanager` is located in android_sdk/tools/bin/.
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager
```

[View more details on the new `sdkmanager`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html).

> Select and install the required tools. *(your location may be different)*

### 2. Install and accept android license via command line:

Update the packages via command line, you'll be presented with the terms and conditions which you'll need to accept.

#### - Install or update to the latest version

This will install the latest `platform-tools` at the time you run it.

```
# Android SDK Tools 25.2.3 and lower. Install the latest `platform-tools` for android-25
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools,android-25,extra-android-m2repository

# Android SDK Tools 25.2.3 and higher
sdkmanager --update
```

#### - Install a specific version (`25.0.1`, `24.0.1`, `23.0.1`)

You can also install a specific version like so:

```
# Build Tools 23.0.1, 24.0.1, 25.0.1
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-25.0.1,android-25,extra-android-m2repository
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-24.0.1,android-24,extra-android-m2repository
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.1,android-23,extra-android-m2repository
# Alter the versions as required                      ↑               ↑

# -u --no-ui  : Updates from command-line (does not display the GUI)
# -a --all    : Includes all packages (such as obsolete and non-dependent ones.)
# -t --filter : A filter that limits the update to the specified types of
#               packages in the form of a comma-separated list of
#               [platform, system-image, tool, platform-tool, doc, sample,
#               source]. This also accepts the identifiers returned by
#               'list sdk --extended'.

# List version and description of other available SDKs and tools
android list sdk --extended
sdkmanager --list
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know why but using this command worked like a charm and the licence is accepted.
I just replaced version 25.0.1 by 25.0.2 for latest version ;)

Comment: `./sdkmanager --update` triggered the agreement for me.

Comment: I dont have a Library folder for my user...

Comment: Did not trigger the agreement for me

Comment: I just get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema when I run ./sdkmanager --licenses
 :( - any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't find the required build tools in the GUI sdk manager. Command line worked like a charm!

Comment: @RomanGaufman You ever find a solution to your comment, I am running into the same issue?

Comment: Same issue for me as @RomanGaufman

Comment: @RomanGaufman What helped for me was to install Java 8 and have JAVA_HOME point to it. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51644855/665780) you can also do `set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.xml.bind` prior to executing sdkmanager, but this did not work for me

Comment: @jamesemanon I solved this issue:
1) open android studio.
2) Go to Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System settings -> Android  SDK.
3) Click on the SDK tools tab.
4) Search for Android SDK command-line tools and install them.

Answer (score 135):

Go to your `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`
and fire the cmd

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Accept All licenses listed there.

After this just go to the licenses folder in sdk and check that it's having these five files:

```
android-sdk-license, android-googletv-license, android-sdk-preview-license, google-gdk-license, mips-android-sysimage-license
```

Give a retry and build again, still jenkins giving 'licenses not accepted'  then you have to give full permission to your 'sdk' directory and all it's parent directories. Here is the command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/
```

If you having sdk in /opt/ directory.

Comment: In case of windows path would be like - `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`, and command `sdkmanager --licenses``./` not needed for windows.

Comment: thanks @garg10may running `./sdkmanager --licenses` in powershell worked perfectly for all the SDKs I installed via Android Studio which I only installed to use Phonegap CLI - I dont have any Android Studio projects

Comment: @garg10may i am not having bin folder under tools folder on windows10 what should i do ?

Comment: I tried `sudo chmod -R 775 /opt/` and it didn't work, with `777` everything worked ok, thanks!

Comment: I have been struggling with this problem for days and `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/` finally fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: On Windows 10 opening cmd with administrator privileges and then typing cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\ and then sdkmanager --update worked for me. After that I just had to press "y" twice in order to accept the licenses.

Comment: licenses folder is missing , what to do ?

Comment: The solution will also work in React Native https://aboutreact.com/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components/

Comment: I'm on Windows and there is no `tools` folder in `/Android/Sdk/`.

Comment: NEVER do this """ sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/"""  You could break so many programs . Try to find a better solution .

Comment: Running `chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/android-sdk/` and accepting the license solved it on my Ubuntu

Comment: You'll need JAVA 8. Don't use newer versions of Java.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Jefferson, I was getting a ClassNotFoundException when trying with a newer java version, changing my JAVA_HOME to the jdk8 home (temporarily) did it.

Answer (score 98):

I have resolved the problem by using the command:

> 1. Go to: C:\Users\ [PC NAME] \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\ (If the folder is not available then download the Android SDK first, or
>    you can install it from the android studio installation process.)
> 2. Shift+Left click and Press W, then Enter to open CMD on the folder path
> 3. Type in the cmd: sdkmanager --licenses
> 4. Once press enter, you need to accept all the licenses by pressing y

Checking the licenses

> 1. Go to: C:\Users\ [PC NAME] \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\
> 2. Check the folder named licenses

```
android-googletv-license
android-sdk-license
android-sdk-preview-license
google-gdk-license
intel-android-extra-license
mips-android-sysimage-license
```

**AS NEW UPDATE FOLDER PATH** (Current Android Studio)

Open Android Studio, Tools > Sdk Manager > Android SDK Command-Line Tools (Just Opt-in)

[image]

SDKManager will be store in :

> 1. Go to C:\Users\ [PC NAME] \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin
> 2. Type in the cmd: sdkmanager --licenses

Documentation to using the Android SDK: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Comment: Thank you!!! Using the sdk-manager available after following your install directions and path you suggested above (I use Arch Linux so --> `/home/[USER]/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager`) allowed me to get past the licenses issue! The `sdkmanager` installed by Android SDK here `/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager` seems to be broken.

Comment: not windows, but `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.`

Comment: that JAVA_HOME is a separate error.
Download JDK 11 (preferably 11) - https://jdk.java.net/archive/ -> extract -> create new path in environment variables and add the directory as JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 65):

**For Windows users w/o using Andoid Studio:**

1. Go to the location of your `sdkmanager.bat` file. Per default it is at `Android\sdk\tools\bin` inside the `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder.
2. Open a terminal window there by typing cmd into the title bar
3. Type

   ```
   sdkmanager.bat --licenses
   ```
4. Accept all licenses with 'y'

Comment: I found this in Program Files, and it didn't maintain accepting of licenses until I ran As Administrator

Comment: One thing to note here if you're from the UK, spelling, make sure you spell `licenses` the US way, not `licences` as we would in the uk - simple mistake that had me stumped for a minute, not seeing wood for trees

Comment: If you have this error in Unity as I did. Restart it after accepting licenses.

Answer (score 57):

**Update for macOS Sierra 10.12.6 - Android Studio for Mac 2.3.3**

Locate the sdkmanager file usually under:

```
/Users/YOUR_MAC_USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin

./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Warning: `File /Users/mtro.josevaler**strong text**io/.android/repositories.cfg` could not be loaded.
6 of 6 SDK package licenses not accepted.
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? **Y**

To validate the problem has gone just repeat the operation involved in the license issue.

Comment: I'm not able to locate 'tools' folder presend in Android/sdk directory... Did thorough walk throw but didn't find it.  Wokring on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.4 and Android Studio 3.6.3. Can help?

Answer (score 38):

I solved the problem by opening the Android SDK Manager and installing the SDK build tools for the version it is complaining about (API 24).

I had also updated using the command line previously and I suspect the Android SDK Manager has a more complete way of resolving dependencies, including the license.

Comment: This works for GUI SDK Manager, but unfortunately doesn't for commandline.

Comment: Use @Anil 's answer for a command line explanation

Comment: I've solved the problem by  installing the SDK Platform of the version it is complaining about (eg: api 27)

Answer (score 29):

Maybe I'm late, but this helped me accept SDK licenses for OSX,

If you have android SDK tools installed, run the following command

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Accept all licenses by pressing `y`

Voila! You have accepted SDK licenses and are good to go..

Comment: On macOS you can use `yes | ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` to automatically accept them all, on Linux use `y | ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`. `y` is basically the same as `yes`, it just outputs `y` to accept until there is no more input requested and the process stops.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use the IDE to accept the license, I also found it easy to open up Android Studio and create a new basic project to trigger the license agreements. Once I created a project, the following licensing dialog was presented that I needed to agree to:

[image]

I documented fully the information in the following post: [Accepting the Android SDK License via Android Studio](http://www.allenconway.net/2017/11/accepting-android-sdk-license-via.html)

Answer (score 15):

I had a similiar problem but ./sdkmanager --licenses didnt work. I follow this thread and "obladors" comment gave me the solution:
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/527

What eventually solved my problem was:
Running  `./sdkmanager "build-tools;23.0.1"`

Change 23.0.1 with your version

Answer (score 14):

You can accept the license agreement by launching Android Studio, then going to:

> Help > Check for Updates...

When you are installing updates, it'll ask you to accept the license agreement. Accept the license agreement and install the updates, and you are all set.

Comment: Excellent Gregory R. I tried it in the command line and a few other ways and this one was the only on that worked.

Answer (score 13):

I ran across this error when i ran *cordova build android*

I solved this issue by firing ./sdkmanager --licenses and accepting all the licenses.

1. You have a sdkmanager.bat under the android sdk folder in the path: android/sdk/tools/bin
2. To trigger that open a command prompt in android/sdk/tools/bin
3. type ./sdkmanager --licenses and enter
4. Press y to review all licenses and then press y to accept all licenses

Comment: useful for those who develop with react-native and similar frameworks

Answer (score 8):

In linux

```
 1. Open a terminal
 2. Write: "cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin (this path can be /home/your-user/Android/Sdk/tools/bin)"
 3. Write: "./sdkmanager --licenses"
 4. To accept All licenses listed, write: "y"
 5. Ready!
```

If your are building an app with Ionic Framework, just write again the command to build it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having this problem for a React Native app, in addition to above mentioned steps, make sure you have the local.properties file in the android directory(AppName/android) of your app which points to your 'sdk' directory:

```
sdk.dir=/PATH_TO_SDK/
```

Comment: For me android app this also was the issue.. Other than executing ``` yes | sdkmanager --licenses && sdkmanager --update```. You need to set the local.properties correctly eg: *sdk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk*. In my case I was giving the wrong pas in ~/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by below steps:

1. update the android sdk with command "tools/android update sdk --no-ui"
2. got to android sdk folder on jenkins machines, create "licenses" folder
3. created file named "android-sdk-license" and paste the license from dev machine