# Android os Bundle is not loading

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working in android studio. The link containing image reflecting the problem i am getting I don't know why, till now it was working fine for me , but  its not working any more, help me out with this , thank you.
 [image]

Comment: Basically its the Bundle Error, the bundle isn't importing i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

remove invalid catches and add the app compact module in setting in your android studio. try it i think its working

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an issue with license of SDK, I solves it by exec:

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

I found this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43931658/641892