# Travis android build failed due to license issue

Tags: android, react-native, travis-ci

travis android build failed with following exception

You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to

travis android configurations :

```
language: android
  os: linux
  jdk: oraclejdk8
  before_cache:
    - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
    - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/
  sudo: required
  node_js: false
  before_install:
    - nvm install 7
    - node --version
    - travis_retry curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
    - echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
    - travis_retry sudo apt-get update -qq
    - travis_retry sudo apt-get install -y -qq yarn
  install:
    - yarn
  android:
    components:
      - build-tools-25.0.3
      - android-25
      - extra-android-m2repository
      - extra-google-google_play_services
      - extra-google-m2repository
      - addon-google_apis-google-16
  script:
    - cd android
    - bundle install
    - bundle exec fastlane deploy
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

Answer (score 1):

Add this under `android:` block:

```
licenses:
  - android-sdk-preview-license-.+
  - android-sdk-license-.+
  - google-gdk-license-.+
```