# When i have build or to run ionic app at that time generate below error

Tags: cordova, ionic2

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 26].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: I have not used android studio and my OS is Windows OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to get the various proposed solutions to work.

```
cd "%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin"
sdkmanager --licenses
```

no longer works.

I found that running

```
sdkmanager --update
```

asked me to accept the license

and then failed due to the `tools` folder being in use.

Notwithstanding, the license problem seemed to be fixed.

The contents of the license file is now:

```
8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55
d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e
```

Hope this helps others that have wasted as much time as I on this.