# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. - Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I've created a new project. I installed "Browser / Android" as the platform.
Only standard plug-ins installed;
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"

It makes a smooth compilation in the browser. (The project is already hollow)
However, I can't get results when I want to compile on android device. The output is as follows. I also share SDK information. I don't know where I'm making a mistake.

[image: SDK Screenshot]

```
C:\MyApp>cordova run android -device

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions 

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk (DEPRECATED)

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as i
t is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.
0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gr
adle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default versio
n of the build tools.
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\25.0.1\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\25.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\25.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\26.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\26.0.1\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\26.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\26.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\28.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\an
droid\m2repository\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\auto\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\google_play_services\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\instantapps\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\m2repository\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\market_apk_expansion\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\market_licensing\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\simulators\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\usb_driver\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\webdriver\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-
tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-23\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-25\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-26\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-27\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-Q\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-im
ages\android-28\android-tv\x86\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-im
ages\android-28\default\x86_64\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\pac
kage.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\25.0.1\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\25.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\25.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\26.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\26.0.1\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\26.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\26.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-too
ls\28.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\an
droid\m2repository\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\auto\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\google_play_services\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\instantapps\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\m2repository\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\market_apk_expansion\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\market_licensing\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\simulators\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\usb_driver\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\go
ogle\webdriver\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-
tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-23\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not
 been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missi
ng components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to anot
her, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU?LD FAILED in 1s
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-25\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-26\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-27\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
\android-Q\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-im
ages\android-28\android-tv\x86\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-im
ages\android-28\default\x86_64\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\pac
kage.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
C:\MyApp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output
:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not
 been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missi
ng components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to anot
her, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU?LD FAILED in 1s

C:\MyApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

At your `Android SDK Build Tools` uninstall version 28.0.2 and install version 28.0.3.

These are in your screenshot 1st Window the 3rd and the 4th packages.

It looks that cordova does not have the permission to do it as it posts the error `Probably the SDK is read-only`.

Another possible solution for that is to start the cmd as an administrator and try again.

Comment: permissions of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` could also cause troubles.

Comment: This should be the root cause but if he tries to move it, then most probably he will break all path references that may exist in the machine, and solving this will be a bigger problem ;-)

Comment: I ran SDK Manager as an administrator. As you said, I uninstalled 28.0.2 and installed 28.0.3.
I ran CMD as an administrator. But the problem did not improve.

Comment: Maybe then the only option is to try moving the Android SDK to another location ie. `C:\Android\android-sdk` but this requires to update any `environment variables` and other references that may looking for it in the old location. And still not quarantee that the problem will solved. :(

Comment: It may also related to this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026963/android-sdk-platform-26-license-error-in-ionic-3

Comment: I don't know how to move the Android SDK. I think that moving with a cut + paste creates problems. I'm trying to find solutions to your link. But I can't get results.

Comment: That exact answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124015/944070 but your location is under program files. Just copy the licenses as proposed. Create the path if it does not exist.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do this. "C: \ Android \ sdk" does not have such a folder. I also don't understand what they mean when they say "License folder".