# whenever I run new project in react-native i get error message that is android sdk license are not accepted how to get rid with this permanently?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-application

Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary SDK licenses using SDK Manager: "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses". Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

I am using VScode as editor and i have RN version - 61.0.5
**"$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses"** i have used this command but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: and did you go through the setup and enter yes for all the prompts?

Comment: When i run the command i get all the licenses accepted and computing updates as output over cmd i didn't get any stuff to do yes for all the prompts i am using android studio 3.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link that will help you: [You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

You need to accept the licenses through the terminal/prompt

e.g on linux:

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/
```

Run the sdkmanager as follows:

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

e.g on Windows:

```
cd /d "%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%/tools/bin"
```

Run the sdkmanager as follows:

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

And accept the licenses you did not accept yet (but need to).

Comment: is it need any system restart because i have tried this but still getting same error

Comment: after running above command i did stuff from this answer and it works https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124015/12484443