# Unable to run flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to run sample flutter app. I downloaded flutter SDK. Since I am an Android developer I had android SDK. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Using Android Studio 3.0.1 created a new Flutter Application (Flutter plugin was installed). Now when I try to run the APP, It is giving following error -

> Error running Gradle: Unable to download needed Android SDK
>   components, as the following licenses have not been accepted: Android
>   SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2, Android SDK Platform 27

And it suggested

> To resolve this, please run the following command in a Terminal:
>   flutter doctor --android-licenses

I followed the instruction. Still, I am getting the same error message.

> Error running Gradle: Unable to download needed Android SDK
>   components, as the following licenses have not been accepted: Android
>   SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2, Android SDK Platform 27

I have tried - `./sdkmanager --licenses` But no success.

[image]

Comment: follow this [How to accept android sdk license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with sdk path in local.properties. By default its pointing to different location. Once I changed sdk.dir to my Android SDK path, it worked fine. I am able to run the app now.