# Ionic Cordova Build Android Error With Gradle And Build Failed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Please help me to solve this problem. I don't know how to solve this problem because I've already tried all methods that I know of, but I'm still getting a Gradle error.

[image: Please Look At This Screenshot]

I've already added the new system variable name : _JAVA_OPTIONS and the value : -Xmx512M. The error is still same. Please help me if you can.

```
$ ionic cordova platform list

cordova platform ls

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

Installed platforms: android 6.4.0
Available platforms: browser ~5.0.1
ios ~4.5.4
osx ~4.0.1
windows ~5.0.0
www ^3.12.0
```

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your error:

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following sdk components [Android SDK Platform 26]

You must accept a license in the SDK Manager, please check [theses answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

Comment: LulzSec@HyperProject MINGW32 /
$ cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

LulzSec@HyperProject MINGW32 ~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
$ ./sdkmanager --licenses
bash: ./sdkmanager: No such file or directory

so how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Try opening the sdkmanager.exe that should be in your ANDROID_HOME/sdk folder, if it does not open, try using the Android Studio UI, and then download/update the SDK Platform 26, make sure to accept the license when asked

Comment: i've already update and accept license in android studio . Now i'm get new error . Please look at this screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfxcB.png

Comment: so how to solve this problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfxcB.png ? 
you know ? hope you can help me . thank you

Comment: I've never seen that error, try removing and adding the platform, sometimes it gets corrupted. Which cordova version are you using?

Comment: I'm use Condova : 8.0.0 | cordova-android@6.4.0 . i've already add again platform but problem still same.