# How to setup bitbucket pipelines in android correctly

Tags: android, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket pipelines A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:

this is my `build.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# Add Android SDK license in a default file
mkdir -p "{$ANDROID_HOME}/licenses"
echo -e "<My license>" > "{$ANDROID_HOME}/licenses/android-sdk-license"
echo -e "<My license>" > "{$ANDROID_HOME}/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"

# Build the app
./gradlew assembleProductionRelease
```

this is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
image: uber/android-build-environment:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - unset ANDROID_NDK_HOME
          - echo “Start default step”
          - bash ./build.sh
          - echo "Amazing"
```

> PS:im using bitbucket pipeline, ur link is using local android sdk.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

Comment: im using bitbucket pipeline, ur link is using local android sdk.

Comment: The correct commands in a shell script are the same in both cases.

Comment: did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be related with stale CI image, which does not accept licenses by default. Or downloads latest SDK dependencies without accepting them.

Please try using: `image: androidsdk/android-30`: [Bitbucker blog post](https://bitbucket.org/blog/automate-and-scale-your-android-deployment-with-bitbucket-pipelines)

There is also a manual way to make it, however the image itself should provide working environment: [manual way](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Licence-Agreement-not-being-accepted-due-to-which-Android-build/qaq-p/722183?lightbox-message-images-1421036=101285iF60B5EB5991EE996)