# stop downloading of gradle during react native project running

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I am working on react native android project.I have initiated my first android react native project as i am begginer. When i run my app, it showed me this error in my `cmd terminal`. How can i fix it??

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
File C:\Users\hasee\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 in C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 23 in C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 23 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.997 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin` Run:`./sdkmanager --licenses`

Check the following answer [You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)