# How to include the material-design library

Tags: android, ant, material-design

I want to include the material-design library for android into my project, but I'm a bit confused where to find it and how to include it. I downloaded the library from github https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android.

I tried to build it with gradle, but I got the following error, to which I can't seem to find the solution:

```
> Configure project :catalog
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in /mnt/sda2/android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':catalog'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
```

I have the 'build-tools 27.0.3' installed through the SDK manager. Any hints please on how can I bypass this issue?

As far as I understood, I need to compile the library in the first place, then place it into the /lib folder, and then tell 'Ant' build tool to include this library in order to use it. Is this correct? Maybe there's a place from which I can simply download already pre-compiled lib? I couldn't seem to locate it in the SDK manager. Thank you!

I'm trying to build the project with Gradle now, this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
  }
}
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Any hints please?

**UPDATE**

I downloaded android studio, followed the instructions, here's a snippet of my build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
}
```

but now I'm getting a different error:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:design:25.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

I opened the SDK manager, but he Android Support Repository is already installed (rev47). Any hints please? Thanks!

Comment: you dont need to download the library just use gradle to import it in your project. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: @tyczj thanks, but how can I do this if I'm using 'Ant' builder?

Comment: I dont believe and is supported. are you not using android studio?

Comment: @tyczj thanks. For some reason it's extremely lagy on my laptop, I will download and give it another shot, thanks for the hint. Meanwhile can you please check my build.gradle, any hints on the error? Thanks!

Comment: @tyczj I installed android studio and did as mentioned in the instructions, but now I'm getting a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope following things help you :-

```
**A problem occurred configuring project ':catalog'.Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
 build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3**
```

1. You need to accept the licence first, check the link here for your licence issue :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41078173/2919483
2. For adding material design library in Android studio :-

   ```
    In you build.gradle, add the dependency like:

    dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
                 }
   ```

sync your project and start using that.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but I got a new error, can you please check? I updated my question.

Comment: Can you please post your build.gradle for both Module and APP

Comment: sorry, my bad, I placed it inside the main 'dependencies' section, instead of for 'module', now everything is working fine, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your **compiledSdkVersion is 28**

In build.gradle, make sure that the repositories section includes Google's Maven repository google()
i.e.,

add this

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

Then, add the dependencies.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

**Then Refactor to AndroidX.**

Click on Refactor and then click on Migrate to AndroidX.

Then it will update your app's dependencies and code to use the newly packaged androidx and com.google.android.material libraries.

**or**

You can use com.android.support:design:28.0.0 dependency if you do not wish to switch to androidx.

**Note:** You cannot use both com.android.support and com.google.android.material dependencies in your app at the same time.