# Android Studio Error About Gradle And License

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter

I'm using ubuntu and I am coding with flutter in android studio. When my run my first app, android studio give me this error.

I am already tried what error text told me. 
Here's the error

[image: error]

Comment: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003932/7987910) can give you a nice guideline to solve this issue.