# Flutter: Cannot build an app on android emulator

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build an app on Android emulator, but my android studio gives me an error saying,

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Failed to install the following
>   Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
>        build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
>        platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing
>   components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.   Alternatively, to
>   transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see
>   http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
>
> Using Android SDK: /Users/haraharada/Library/Android/sdk
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3s

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using Mac and Android studio. I can build and see my app using Xcode simulator but for the android device, I cannot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to run `flutter doctor -v` command in your terminal to see what went wrong? It's clearly that's something wrong with your android SDK license. You might want to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003932/11647762) and try again

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had to agree the licensing for Android SDK.