# Build failed with CMD line --ionic cordova build android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-3

I am facing issues and not able to find solution. Created an simple app with Ionic and cordova, Setup all enviroment variable { like JAVA_HOME, Android/sdk, Platform-tool, Gradle} and as usual ionic cordova build android  command worked fine.
I did somechanges like calling external data with HttpClient, And again when I am going to build with same command, facing below issues. Please help me to resolve.[image]

> cordova.cmd build android
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android (DEPRECATED)
> Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib
> Subproject Path: app
> Observed package id 'build-tools;29.0.3' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3' (Expected 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\build-tools\29.0.3')
> Observed package id 'emulator' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator' (Expected 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\emulator')
> Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' (Expected 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager')
> Observed package id 'patcher;v4' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4' (Expected 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\patcher\v4')
> Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools')
> Observed package id 'sources;android-29' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-29' (Expected 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sources\android-29')
> Observed package id 'system-images;android-R;google_apis_playstore;x86' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-R\google_apis_playstore\x86' (Expected 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\system-images\android-R\google_apis_playstore\x86')
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\tools')
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\licenses
> Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 29 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Command failed with exit code 1: D:\test\project\crud-app\ionic app\ionic-test\riagitanjali\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\test\project\crud-app\ionic app\ionic-test\riagitanjali\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

D:\test\project\crud-app\ionic app\ionic-test\riagitanjali>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

Answer (score 1):

You have to Accept Licenses for the Android SDK.

open CMD and Run command:

```
cd /d "%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%/tools/bin"
```

then Run:

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

and press Y on every step to accept license.

Comment: Actually My builds are failing, but not sure whats the issue.

Comment: actually Issue is not resolved. I am trying to build the application in Android..with 
ionic cordova build android       command

Comment: Actually Error received when run below command
---   cordova build android

Comment: Any suggestion before to run      cordova build android         to fix the error??

Comment: what Version of JAVA JDK are you using??

Answer (score 0):

JAVA JDK is metioned on above attached image as JAVA_HOME i.e. Java\jdk1.8.0_202