# How can I include "Android" in the drop down list for project folder setup in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I recently downloaded Android Studio 4.1.1 on a new computer and I want my file structure to be similar to what I had on an old macbook running Android Studio 3.5.2.

I am new to Android Development, so I don't know the terminology, but I included some screenshots to show what I am talking about. On my old computer (3.5.2) I had the option for an "Android" dropdown list. This isn't even an option in the new 4.1.1 Android Studio.

[image: Bad Style]
(BAD^)

[image: Bad]
(BAD^)

[image: CorrectPhoto]
(GOOD)

Things I have tried:

- File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
- Adding a new module. But I don't know how to set this up. (File -> Project Structure -> Module)
- According to [Android Studio Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects), repos come by default with and "Android View"

Comment: Try to import the project instead of opening the project.

Comment: From the images, I can see that in the 'bad' pictures, you are opening projects that are not android projects. for example 'google-chrome.app'

Answer (score 0):

[You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

^This post solved it for me. It didn't recognize the project as an "Android" Project. I was getting an error "license for package android sdk build tools not accepted 28.0.3."

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/
```

I navigated to the correct folder and was asked to go through and accept the additional licenses.

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

*I can now view it in the proper file structure with Android as a drop down