# Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted. platform 29

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-2.3

I have this error aobut accept the sdk license agreements

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
     platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
  
  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk
```

I have two android-sdk

one in /usr/lib/android-sdk and the other in home/bug/Android/Sdk

```
 yes | $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.2"
Warning: File /home/bug/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.          
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
```

with this command I accept in home/bug/Android------

but How to accept the license in /usr/lib/android-sdk????

Comment: Have you tried this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43931658/7689896 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem copying the licenses into /usr/lib/android-sdk

```
sudo cp -R licenses /usr/lib/android-sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
yes |  /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

I am not sure but you may also require to create the `repositories.cfg` file:

```
mkdir ~/.android
echo "count=0" > ~/.android/repositories.cfg
```