# ionic cordova build error: Failed to install android sdk packages

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, android-sdk-2.3

I was trying to generate the apk file from an ionic cordova project and after having installed jdk and android-sdk in my ubuntu machine, setting the path variables and executing "ionic cordova platform add android" I executed the command "ionic cordova build android" which after running of some time produced the following error.

Please tell me what i need to do, I've been working on this all day.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 29.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 29.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 29 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
     platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28m 36s
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to accept the licenses, open android studio, you will find the configure button, click there and go in manage sdk.
an easier way is the create a blank project in android studio and build it will also accept the terms.

[here is where you will find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Leo4.png)

Comment: Can I do it without using android studio from the ubuntu terminal. My machine isn't beefy enough to run android studio. Please please, tell me how I can accept licences fron terminal I have android sdk installed

Comment: hm i never did it without android studio, but this answer shows how to accept the licenses with the terminal : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components