# Unable to start emulator in CMD first Appcelerator project

Tags: android, appcelerator

I've been trying to get Appcelerator setup properly and to run the first project that is run on their ["Get Started"](https://platform.axway.com/#/product/cli) page.  All the dependencies have been installed, but when I attempt to run the first project by typing the command "appc run --platform android", I receive the errors

"[ERROR] Unable to start emulator "Pixel_3a_API_27"

[ERROR] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5037"

I have noticed that the emulator listed changes based upon the emulators I create in Android Studio, but none of them will run, they just come back with the same error but the available emulator is listed.  For example, if API_30 is available, the error will list "Pixel_3a_API_30"

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by accepting the licenses for SDK:

[You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components)

And, running the emulator manually through Android Studio before running the CMD commands