# Flutter Desktop Application Running error MSB4100

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio, dart, desktop-application

So, what I was trying to do is to build Windows desktop apps with Flutter. I just followed all the steps of installation that were written in the documentation of Flutter. I just created a simple boilerplate with the command `flutter create learningflutter` on my Windows 11 machine. Then I just run the `flutter run -d windows` command inside the directory (`learningflutter`), then ended up with this error:

```sh
$ flutter run -d windows
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(469,26): error MSB4100: Expected "$([System.String]::new('%(Link.AdditionalDependencies)').Contains('atls.lib'))" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "$([System.String]::new('..\flutter\Debug\flutter_wrapper_app.lib;D:\Adil's Files\My Code\learningflutter\windows\flutter\ephemeral\flutter_windows.dll.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib').Contains('atls.lib'))", in condition "'$(ATL_KeyFile)' != '' and ('$(ConfigurationType)' == 'Application' or '$(ConfigurationType)' == 'DynamicLibrary') [D:\Adil's Files\My Code\learningflutter\build\windows\runner\learningflutter.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(469,26): error MSB4100:                          and %(Link.AdditionalDependencies) != '' and  $([System.String]::new('%(Link.AdditionalDependencies)').Contains('atls.lib'))". [D:\Adil's Files\My Code\learningflutter\build\windows\runner\learningflutter.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...
Exception: Build process failed.
```

I was looking for how to fix this problem. Would be appreciated if you teachers can help me out with this problem!

My Flutter Doctor configuration:

```sh
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.13.0-0.0.pre.498, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22593.1], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.66.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

You can say that I have literally no idea about Flutter, and never made a mobile app with it. So, you can treat me a newbie and please explain why you did this or that or whatever so that I can learn.

> If you need more information, please ask for it explicitly. I never dealt with these problems before so I don't really know specifically what to include as a reference! Thanks for your consideration!

Thank you Sir/Ma'am!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you downloaded cmdline-tools

> Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`

and for the sdk license issue you may check [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41078173/14286760)

Comment: He's running for windows.  It's doubtful that the dependencies for android would be relevant for windows flutter development - and Flutter Doctor is indicating that Visual studio for windows was ok