# I can't open an existing react-native project

Tags: react-native

I get the following error when I run this command

```
 react-native run-android
```

> Configure project :react-native-onesignal
>   WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
>   It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Configure project :react-native-webview
>   :react-native-webview:reactNativeAndroidRoot C:\Users\VO\Desktop\xxxx\xxxx\node_modules\react-native\android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: 1. For Android, you need to manually start the emulator, Have you done that?
2. Go through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119301/installdebug-not-found-in-root-project-android-react-native

Comment: @iRohitBhatia I tried but I couldn't. I try react-native run-android --variant [projectName]

Comment: You couldn't start emulator?

Comment: unfortunately does not open. Can you connect with teamviewer?

Comment: sorry, I can't connect with team viewer but in mac (which I use) for android you need to manually start Android and then do react-native run-android. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: I tried but I got this error this time.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-facebook-account-kit:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First check these:**

1. Check that you have installed all your dependencies correctly or not.
2. **react-native-webview** and other plugins giving error then try to fix it.
3. Gradle version are important for specific plugin usage so check it also that you are using supported Gradle version.

**Follow these steps:**

1. Close all metro bundles
2. **watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache**
3. open **Android Studio** and **open yourprojectname/android**
4. Let **Android Studio sync** and if there any sync **issue then fix it**.
5. Go to **File menu** -> **invalidate cache and restart**
6. Before **react-native run-android** try to check you have open device or emulator
7. Check it with **adb devices**
8. Now try once.

Comment: I think that the project info is less for solving your issue. Give us some information to solve this:

- react-native info (with this we all know everything is installed correctly)
- provide your package.json code here
- provide screenshot of the issue when you are trying react-native run-android
- Tell us when you were last able to run the app and when it breaks?