# react native 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

```
when i run: $ react-native run-android

Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

details:

"react-native": "0.62.0"
"react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.2"
```

---

### Gradle 6.0.1

Build time:   2019-11-18 20:25:01 UTC
Revision:     fad121066a68c4701acd362daf4287a7c309a0f5

Kotlin:       1.3.50
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_231 (Oracle Corporation 25.231-b11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: is your emulator is running??

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['installDebug' not found in root project 'android' React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119301/installdebug-not-found-in-root-project-android-react-native)

Comment: The adb server was running. I killed it and am about to try again from scratch.